# Synchronizations issues in dockerizeed microservices

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, axios

I have dockerized microservices written in Node.js, and there are instances where some services are up before the services it depends on are up, hence there are some synchronization issues that cause connection refused errors.

I primarily use `HTTP` for communications between services

I currently use pause and retries wherever necessary, but that is more of a hack, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if your services *depend on* other services, then it may be time to re-evaluate their boundaries. A service is supposed to be autonomous. If it's not, you have a coupling problem and it may be best to merge the services so that they start together, perhaps even in the same Node process. Sure, the microservice architecture dictates both physical and logical separation of services. This is sometimes a trap that causes them to be less reliable, not more independent.

Secondly, distributed systems must deal with the network being unreliable. In this context, retries are the way to go - it's not a hack, it's a fact of life that some connections will fail every now and then. You have the option of treating the connection attempt at start-up like any other retry: repeat to infinity. What's most important that your service doesn't pretend that it's *ready* or *healthy* when it's not connected to the stuff it needs.